# Obtaining multiple y (output) values for an input X using Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, supervised-learning

I am currently working on this weather dataset.

[image: This is how the dataset looks like]

The dataset contains 5 columns and 1632 rows. I have tried out SVM models which outputs a single Y (Temperature or Pressure or Humidity) value and have trained 3 different models for each weather parameter.

But is there any way with which I can obtain values for Temperature,Humidity and Pressure as outputs (with Place and Month being inputs) using **one single prediction model?** Is it possible to obtain these values as a single output vector consisting of 3 values?
 I've just started with Machine Learning so I'm not really familiar with the advanced concepts. I tried searching for possible solutions online but couldn't find much. Any help and suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Not all models can explicitly handle multidimensional output, but yes it is possible using some multivariate models. What software are you using?

Comment: @Robert Milletich Currently, I am scripting on Python 2 using Conda . If you meant my laptop specs, its a 12 GB Ram I5 core processor.

Comment: Nope -- referring to software (i.e., Python, R, etc.). Check out this post from cross validated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/153853/regression-with-scikit-learn-with-multiple-outputs-svr-or-gbm-possible.

Comment: Multi-output regressor worked perfectly. Thanks alot!